# Magick.NET png conversion very slow

Tags: c#, imagemagick, png, tiff

I'm converting a very large tif image (203MB) to png using Magick.NET in a C# console project.
The image is converted succesfully but, even setting the Quality parameter to 0, it takes about 20 seconds.
This is the code I use:

```
using (var image = new MagickImage(imageBytes, settings))
{
    image.Format = MagickFormat.Png;
    image.Quality = compressionLevel;
    archivedPath = Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".png");
    image.Write(archivedPath);
}
```

Even calling ImageMagick from CLI I get the same timing.
I also tried doing the same using .NET System.Drawing and I get the same result in about 2 seconds:

```
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(fileName);
bmp1.Save("converted.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

I suspect that I'm missing something about ImageMagick's settings.

Comment: Check Task Manager while ImageMagick's is running and verify the memory usage.  Slow response could mean you are using all the available memory.

Comment: Tried asking that on the ImageMagick github repository? I mean experts on the matter "might" be here but they "will" be on github.